# Cancel account removal request

Tags: support

Last week, I got upset about my friend for getting me a question ban and decided to close my account. I sent a message asking to close my account but now after earning some reputation, I lifted the ban. Will they still remove my account one day, even though I changed my mind?

I would like to remain 'Wolfdog' (my name).

Comment: A "*friend*" getting you question-banned? ;-)

Comment: By the way names aren't unique on StackOverflow. I could change my name to Wolfdog now without issue.

Comment: @Amicable What happens if two people with the same name are in the same comment string and someone @-mentions them? Do they both get notified? Neither?

Comment: Your account shows it's suspended :|

Comment: @dav_i I think it has the same effect as plugging in a UPS into itself.

Comment: @amicable Infinite power?

Comment: Your friend has been detected?

Answer (score 48):

After the stackexchange team have processed your request, you will get a mail, which says

> Hello,
>
> Per your request, your account has been scheduled for removal. You can cancel this request by logging into your profile and clicking the banner shown there; otherwise, your account will be automatically deleted within 24 hours. Please let us know if you need anything else.
>
> Regards,
> The Stack Exchange team

If you didn't get this mail, wait until you get it. Then follow these steps and your account won't get removed.

Comment: So don't go on vacation or anything until you get it;-)